# Attribute transformation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm in process of creating XSLT transformation.
My source XML contains element Order with attribute InstrumentType:

```
<Order InstrumentType="FWD">
```

Now, as part of transformation process I have to use the **attribute value** in condition like:

```
<xsl:if test="$InstrumentType='SPOT'">
...
</xsl:if>
```

I'm looking for some way to get the **attribute value** into InstrumentType **variable** in XSLT.
Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you need a variable? Can't you just use `@InstrumentType` directly?

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="InstrumentType" select="@InstrumentType" />`

Comment: I tried using @InstrumentType but i'm not getting a value of the attribute. When debugging I see value type item().
Any other suggestions or i'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have default namespace problem. Then you can use

```
<xsl:if test="@*[local-name()='InstrumentType' and .='SPOT']"></xsl:if>
```